# Architecture for base builder implemented with Unity. How to get a massive amount of worker?

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine, architecture

I'm new to unity and on the verge to build a base builder.

I was following the tutorial of quill18creates here:
[Video tutorial](https://youtu.be/_lQw3YA7Jok)

and realized that his implementation isn't even close to be capable to process multiple "worker" at the same time. I added multi threading to fix this issue. So the game is able to run a few hundred "worker" without lag.

It's just a proof on concept and it's pretty clear that the code would need a whole work over. Unity has added a https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap.html feature since the creation of the tutorial. The performance of the tilemap convinced me to follow that route.

So a fresh start with my own implementation is what I'm intending.

Can you think of any tips for me? Dos and don'ts?
How is it even possible to get a "worker"/"agent" count like this
[base builder with massive amount of worker](https://youtu.be/dITuxF9Y_3U)

It seems like thousands of workers. Ok, it's pretty obvious to have a limited amount of active workers/agents at a time but still, there are moving alot of guys in that game.

Comment: Well, those workers in the video actually seem to lag (short freeze every few seconds). Also, I would assume that that is another engine so comparison to unity is not really possible. That aside, you could wait for the new entity component system of unity (or work with the beta build) and combine it with the job system (e.g. multithreading, added with 2018.1 I think) of unity. That will probably be your best bet for a "future proof" toolbox. Generally things like task batching (ai tasks, also movement and so on) or intervals on which stuff is done are important points.

Comment: https://simairport.gamepedia.com/Experimental_Patch_Notes_(4_April_2017) The devs are talking about unity themselves. So it is unity. Thx for the advice, I will look up the "entity component system".